# com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Required value 'access_token' missing at $

Tags: android, kotlin, http-post, retrofit, moshi

I try to do post request using retrofit and I use moshi to serialize but I'm not very well versed in these matters. And I am facing such an error, what is the reason for this?

**error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Required value 'access_token' missing at $
> at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.missingProperty(Util.java:649)
> at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapter.fromJson(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:103)
> at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)
> at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:46)
> at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
> at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
> at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
> Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException:
> [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@4eb43d6, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]

**my example response data that I try in postman is like this**

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read",
    "access_token": "WupDsILidLiLşöSAMKvLyI0asdasec",
    "expires_in": 5000,
    "refresh_token": "R9XJBe9FYpgajhqaRO1nIyXscssaSd"
}
```

**my post request response data**

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Parcelize
data class RegisterDto(
    @Json(name = "access_token")
    val access_token: String,
    @Json(name = "expires_in")
    val expires_in: Int,
    @Json(name = "refresh_token")
    val refresh_token: String,
    @Json(name = "scope")
    val scope: String,
    @Json(name = "token_type")
    val token_type: String
) : Parcelable
```

**my data that I send to post request**

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Parcelize
data class RegisterDataModel(

    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @Json(name = "email")
    val email: String,

    @Json(name = "password")
    val password: String,

    @Json(name = "token")
    val token: String

) : Parcelable
```

**my register api**

```
interface RegisterService {

    @POST(API)
    suspend fun postUserData(@Body requestBody:RegisterUiModel ) :  Response<RegisterDto>
}
```

**my repositoryImpl in Data layer**

```
class RegisterRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val registerService: RegisterService
) : RegisterRepository {

    override suspend fun postRegisterData(dataModel: RegisterUiModel):  Response<RegisterDto> {
        return registerService.postUserData(dataModel)
    }
}
```

**Moshi Module in di package**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal class MoshiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
        return Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    }
}
```

**my App module in di package**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(
        moshi: Moshi
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRegisterService(retrofit: Retrofit): RegisterService {
        return retrofit.create(RegisterService::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRegisterRepository(service: RegisterService): RegisterRepository {
        return RegisterRepositoryImpl(service)
    }
}
```

**my post function in viewmodel**

```
fun postService(
       
        registerUiModel: RegisterUiModel
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            val response1 = postRegisterUseCase.postRegisterData(registerUiModel)
          
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if ( response1.code() == 200) {

                    val result1 = response1.toString()
                   

                    // Convert raw JSON to pretty JSON using GSON library
                 //   val adapter = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(Any::class.java).indent("    ")
                  //  val result1 = adapter.toJson(response1.body())
                 
                    Log.d("Pretty Printed JSON : ", result1)
                   
                } else {
                    Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response1.toString())
                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In logcat, the following does not appear when it should, most likely the problem is here

```
 Log.d("Pretty Printed JSON : ", result1)
```

and i feel like i am not using moshi properly. I didn't do anything related to Moshi, as far as I know, retrofit already does it for us. While adding the retrofit in AppModule, I did it like this `.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))`. Doesn't that make it do it automatically anyway?

Comment: I notice that the data class you've stated is the one you're sending is called `RegisterDataModel` however your Retrofit function is taking in a type of `RegisterUiModel`. Did you update the name at some point?

Comment: Sounds like the actual JSON you're receiving is missing the access_toke field. Are you sure it's there in the real response body your client is receiving?